# How do you make a blurry background and in focus div

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make this effect.

[Blurry background : in focus login div form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0XmE.png)

I manage to make everything blurry with filter: blur() . But I don't know how to remove the blur effect from my login form with id = newlogin .

```
 <style>
    body{
      filter: blur(4px);
    }

    #newlogin{
      filter: blur(-4px);
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: A filter affects an element and all of its children. What's most often done in this case is take an single (empty) element, give it a background image and filter: blur it, and then position it absolutely where you need it to be. Or in your example the other way around. Put the pop-up in a separate element that is *not* part of the elements that you want to blur.

Comment: Thanks all you guys, yes that was the approach I was going for. Just was looking to see if there was another nice method I didn't knew :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its nearly impossible to remove filter you applied on body.

Its far more better to apply that filter only on specific object that you want to blur, for exaple give them class "blur_me" and aply blur on that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "unblur" parts of a blurred area like that, every child of the blurred element is also going to appear blurred. You need to either blur every element individually (may look ugly depending on design) or put everything you want to blur in a container and leave everything you don't want blurred outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an idea but idk if it is applicable to your code. Detach the focused div and then insert a glass to your body. Glass will cover whole body and  will be blur. Then attach your detached div to your glass